# Air Core Transformer & Ferrite Core Transformer

Tags: power-supply, power

What is the differnce between a transformer having ferrite core and another transformer without any core (air core transformer).How these two affects the output power and leakage flux??

Comment: Why the downvotes?  Sounds like a reasonable question to me.

Comment: I agree @OlinLathrop

Comment: Question doesn't show any research effort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main reasons ferrite cores are used are: -

- They contain the magnetic field better than air preventing coupling to other circuits
- Higher value inductances can be made with much less copper - trading off copper loss with core loss gives the designer more options.
- Coupling of two or more windings is more effective (should this be required)
- Ferrite solutions (when applicable) are usually physically smaller than air.

The main reasons ferrite cores are not used are: -

- Permeability drifts with temperature hence air cored inductors are more stable in some applications
- Air cores don't saturate and produce 3rd order harmonics like ferrite. Useful, unless you are designing a saturable reactor of course.
- For tuned circuits in the VHF and above, ferrites are too lossy in some applications.

These are the main pros and cons.

Answer (score -2):

Consider the two scenarios.

Without a core, the magnetic field strength is determined by #loops and the current (And many other factors - shape, design, resistance, but we're assuming they're identical for both transformers)

With a ferromagnetic core (Like e.g. Ferrite), applying a magnetic field will induce magnetism in the core, which will increase the magnetic field strength, which will induce magnetism in the core, which will...

As such, you can get a higher field strength from the same current with a ferromagnetic core.

Comment: what about flux leakage??

Comment: Magnetic field strength is not increased with a ferrite core - the core will reduce current due to its increase in permeability. Flux density will increase of course.

Comment: @Andyaka Yes,But there is a little bit confusion about leakage flux.I think that in air core transformer its not easy to control the leakage flux.So is there any way to control the leakage flux?

Comment: @SHASWAT - see my answer - controlling leakage flux is much harder in air cores unless the frequency is high and conductive screens can be used.

Comment: @Andy aka: I am assuming fixed current.

Comment: @Andyaka Could u please elaborate your word "conductive screens"?? and how much amount of high frequency?Is that depends upon output power or something else??

Comment: @medivh What is "use case"

Comment: @SHASWAT take a look at these to see what I mean - they have a metal can around the coil http://www.coilcraft.com/misc/slot7d.html

Comment: "use case" = application or situation